# MagicBook Pro 16 as a development machine?

Tags: laptop, linux, development

I am looking for a laptop for development purposes, hopefully one that will serve well for at least 4-5 years. I do webdev and some other stuff, both at home and on the go.

My main goal is being able to compile code "fast" while a couple IntelliJ projects are open, along with dozens of StackOverflow+YouTube tabs – without anything freezing. I will run Ubuntu. I have some additional "soft requirements" like ergonomics, durability and portability.

Browsing various options, I found Honor's MagicBook Pro 16. It appears to have everything I would need for a development machine (based on stuff I've read online and my limited experience) – 16Gb of RAM, an SSD, and a relatively nice screen. And it has a decent 6-core processor – the one I'm looking at has a Ryzen 5 4600H – based on the specs and benchmarks, seems like it will perform well (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

Also it looks cool which is obviously really important for writing Cool Code.

The reviews I read seem nice and didn't bring up any red flags. Is there anything that I've overlooked? Are there better alternatives for my needs in this price range?

Answer (score 1):

My biggest complain about that honor laptop is the webcam is under the keyboard, which is not nice when video calling and working on code at once, and that is needed during this pandemic.

I would recommend the Lenovo Ideapad 5 Pro 16ACH6 (82L5005TMH) (similar price in Europe) because it has the webcam above the screen, has an sd card slot (I really need that, but thats probably because i'm also video editor :) ) and all the rest is basically the same.